# java | Youtube API : Searching for channels related to a keyword

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can i retrieve a list of channels name ?

so for example :

( i'm searching for "abcde" )  so , if i type "ab" ,the link given below should give me the JSON with the channels name list :
ex.

-abc
 -abbe
 -abcd
 -abcde

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/..../search=ab

i only found this https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=USERNAMEUSER&key={API_KEY}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retreive all channel start with "ad" for example, you need to use the ressource [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) with the parameters:

```
part: snippet
q: "ad" //for example
type: channel
```

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=ad&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The result show you all the YouTube channel starting with "ad"